# linq nested query conditional order by

Tags: entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, sql-order-by

I have a parent query with sub query return child ,
what i need to sort child query according to one property in parent.
here is sudo code:

```
from menu in db.Menus
                     orderby menu.Order
                     select new
                     {
                         Title= menu.Title,
                         OrderNumber = menu.Order,
                         data = (from menuItem in menu.Items
                                  let g = Guid.NewGuid()
                                  orderby g
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                     id = worker.ID,
                                     Title = worker.JobTitle
                                  })
                                 .Take(4)

                     };
```

that works ok,But what i need to sort some menu in random(NewGuid) and sort others with their item priority some thing like it:

```
  let g = Guid.NewGuid()
orderby menu.ISRandom ? g: menuItem.Order
```

But it give error about mismatch guid and int.What's the soloution?
second:How can i replace `take(4) with take(menu.size)`?
thank's

Comment: What is `orderbymenu`?

Comment: sorry,it was syntax error. correction is orderby menu.IsRandom ?
 g:menuItem.Order
@GertArnold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the ordering problem by adding `ToString()`:

```
let g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
orderbymenu.ISRandom ? g : menuItem.Order.ToString()
```

Using `Take(someProperty)` isn't allowed in an EF LINQ query. This is because the take is translated into a `TOP(x)` clause, which can't possibly refer to a column in the SQL result. You can only do this afterwards, after pulling the results into memory without `Take` (or taking some reasonable fixed maximum).

Comment: Wouldn't `ToString` cause incorrect order in case `menuItem.Order` is `int`?

Comment: Yeah, good point. I better change it into one `OrderBy` call that's built conditionally. Depends a bit on what `orderbymenu` is how this should be done.

Comment: If it was a root query, then conditional order by could be an option. For nested it's more complicated - requires LinqKit or similar. I would suggest mutually exclusive `OrderBy` / `ThenBy` - something like `orderby orderbymenu.ISRandom ? Guid.NewGuid() : Guid.Empty, orderbymenu.ISRandom ? 0 : menuItem.Order` :)

Comment: Nice alternative. In retrospect though, I'd prefer to do this in memory too. I'm never fond of cluttering data access code with presentation concerns (the next view want the items ordered by Name, etc.). I tend to wrap such things in a view model that encapsulates conditional ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to read four records from menu.Items at random.

I think you'd be way better off just reading all the items, and then doing the random selection later in code in memory.